Change document icons for Excel files on Windows 11
I am using Office 2021 but installed OneNote from Office 2010 because I need this version for some legacy notes. Except for OneNote, I am using the new applications (Word, Excel, Powerpoint) in 2021.
Now strangely, the document icons of Excel have switched to the look of Office 2010, even though I only installed OneNote. I reinstalled the entire Office 2021 again, but the document icons of Excel documents are still the old ones in the look of 2010.
How can I change them back to Office 2021 like before the installetion of Office 2010?

“How can I change them back to Office 2021 like before the installation of Office 2010?” - You cannot

What are the formats of these files? Are they .xls files?
Can these Office files be opened properly via Office 2021? Please check the default app settings.
